# Smart video thumbnail generator algorithm

Tags: algorithm, video-thumbnails

Hello I'm a Java developer and I'm a part of video on demand website team.

I'm currently doing research on how to implement a back-end component that we are planning to build; the component is expected to automatically generate a meaningful thumbnail representing the content of the videos like the algorithm used in YouTube to generate default thumbnails.

However, I can't seem to find any good open source or payed implementation that can do so, and building the algorithm from scratch is very complicated and needs a lot of time that I don't think the company is willing to invest at the current stage (maybe in the future though)

I would appreciate if someone can refer to any implementation that can help me or even vendors that sell an implementation or a product that can serve my component's objective.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As explained by google research blog:
https://research.googleblog.com/2015/10/improving-youtube-video-thumbnails-with.html

The key component is using a convolutional neural network to predict the score for each sampled frame.

There are so many open sourced CNN implementation like caffe or tensorflow. The only efforts are preparing some training data.